# whitelisting IPs for GCP access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

Is there a way that one can whitelist IPs that can access GCP console. We have GCP setup, but at the moment, one can login to the console from any IP via their gsuite account. How can we limit that to only when on the VPN?

Comment: In order the "white-list" something, it needs to be "black-listed", to begin with.

Comment: I tested a special trick with Access Context Manager and I got a strange error `You are not whitelisted to set conditions. Please contact cloud IAM to request whitelisting`. I suspect an alpha but I'm not in. I think it will be possible soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Cloud Console is a public global resource. AFAIK there is no method to limit access to a user connected via VPN. Access is granted via Google Accounts OAuth Tokens and limiting access to a VPN is not part of the authentication process.